# How do I find the IP address to use in an HTTP request?

Tags: react-native, networking, fetch, ip-address

I want to make an http request via the `fetch()` method in React Native, and I need the IP address of the machine I'm sending the request to. I have access to the machine, and googled "what's my IP" on it. It said my public IP was 162.250.198.98, but when I googled it on another computer nearby, it gave the same address. Is this the right IP to use in a fetch request like this? If not, how do I find the right one to use?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would you use your own IP address to send the request to yourself?  Why aren't you using the server's address?

Comment: I have an API on my local machine, and I'm trying to hit it from an Android device I have connected to it.

Comment: Oh, if they're on the same network, just look up the IP address on your local machine.  You didn't mention what operating system so we can't really tell you how to do this.  On Windows, `ipconfig`.  Linux and others, `ifconfig`.  And, which IP to pick depends on the network it's connected to from there.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. Interestingly, when I google "what's my IP", I get a different IP than if I look it up in System Preferences. Any idea why that would be and which one I should use?

Comment: You should use the IP address for whatever network interface is on the same network as your Android phone.  And, yes, if you look up online what your IP address is, you'll get the IP address of the nearest NAT-ing router, not your computer.  Until IPv6 rollout is finished, we're stuck with NAT where a whole household (or even island) shares the same IP address.

Comment: Re "You should use the IP address for whatever network interface is on the same network as your Android phone": sorry I don't follow what this means. The API I'm trying to hit is on my computer, I looked up the IP address on that computer using System Preferences, and my Android device is plugged into that computer. Should I use that IP address I found when making calls to the API?

Comment: How would we know?  Your computer can and likely does have several network interfaces.  You didn't tell us how your phone and your computer networked.  Pick one and try it, and if it doesn't work, pick the next one.  Eventually you'll figure out what network interfaces are on the network you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple machines connected to the internet via a NAT-enabled router, they will all share the same public IP address. You need to forward a specific port to the machine you want to connect to in the router's configuration e.g. to send your request on port 5000, add a rule to the router to forward port 5000 to your desired machine, then send the request to 162.250.198.98:5000

Comment: when you say "add a rule to the router to forward port 5000 to your desired machine", I'm running my app on an Android, and there's a command `adb reverse` that forwards port 5000 on the Android to port 5000 at that IP address. Is that what you mean? So even though both computers have the same IP, since I'm running the API I'm trying to hit from port 5000 on the one computer and forwarding my device to that port, should that be ok?

Answer (score 0):

For your application to work you need a "server" with a public ip address. Later you assign a domain name to that server/ip address ex. api.domain.com

Since you don't have a server and you are using your computer to test your development, you can do this 2 options:

1. Use your computer IP address usually 192.168.x.x , 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x This will allow you to test it if your phone is connected wireless to the same network.
2. Since you are behind a NAT you can do a port forward to send the traffic to X port to your desired host(ip/port) behind the nat. Usually we create API's that run on port 80 or 443 do a port forward in your router to pass the traffic from this port to your computer ip/port.